# Fill Form Fields with Javascript based on First field

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, url, substr

I have a slight issue I'm trying to find the best solution for.  I have a form where users will enter a url that they copy, it will always be formatted similarly.
Like this: http://www3.google.com/register.php?key=12334123

I would like to be able to populate two fields based on the above input.

Field 1 will be the server (subdomain)

Field 2 will be the key number.

I currently have made something that works, however I think it would be better to do it with  regex as opposed to the way I'm doing it.

Being not too keen on java this is a bit of a challenge for me, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<script language="javascript">
function urlbreaker(url)
{
    var startserver = document.form1.url.value.search(/www/)

    document.form1.server.value = document.form1.url.value.substr(startserver, 4)

    var startkey = document.form1.url.value.search(/=/)
    document.form1.key.value = document.form1.url.value.substr(startkey+1, 10)
}


</script>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label for="url">input url:</label>
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url" onblur="urlbreaker()" />
   http://www3.google.com/register.php?key=12334123</p>
  <p>
    <label for="server">Server:</label>
    <input type="text" name="server" id="server" />
  should be www3</p>
  <p>
    <label for="key">key</label>
    <input type="text" name="key" id="key" />
  should be 12334123</p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function urlbreaker(url)
{
    var match = document.form1.url.value.match(/http:\/\/(.{3,4})\..*?\..*\?(key|.*&key)=(\d*).*/);

    document.form1.server.value = match[1];
    document.form1.key.value = match[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex that matches the host part and key parameter of the url would be:

```
var url = 'http://www3.google.com/register.php?key=12334123';
var match = /[^:]*\/\/([^\/]+)\/[^?]+\?[\s\S]*?key=(\d*)/m.exec(url);
var domain = match[1]; // www3.google.com
var key = match[2]; // 12334123
```

You are asking for the server/subdomain, so if you are wanting the 'www3'

```
var url = 'http://www3.google.com/register.php?key=12334123';
var match = /[^:]*\/\/([^.]+)[^\/]*\/[^?]+\?[\s\S]*?key=(\d*)/m.exec(url);
var domain = match[1]; // www3
var key = match[2]; // 12334123
```